# Is wakelock needed in broadcast receiver for ACTION_SCREEN_OFF

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, wakelock

I'm registering a broadcast receiver that will be activated when the screen is turned off. The receiver performs a short, synchronous operation in OnReceive. This operation must happen in my app before the device sleeps.

My question: do I need to acquire a wakelock here, or is it guaranteed that Android will let my receiver finish the OnReceive method? My code takes a few milliseconds to run, but let's say it takes 1 second for the sake of discussion.

I'm using this code to register the receiver:

```
 BroadcastReceiver receiver = new MyReceiver();
 IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
 context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

I couldn't find an answer in the documentation or by searching, so I would appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: I've been using the SCREEN_OFF-Intent without a wakelock without problems (the code always executes fine), but can't give you a definite answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes device might sleep. Newaz why are you taking a chance? Better aquire a Partial wakelock and release it at the end of onReceive.